# Vertically scroll content within viewport with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

Is there a process to get a website that has a height that overflows the viewport to scroll at certain intervals to the first item that isn't in the view port, and so on for the next page until the bottom is reached and the page is reloaded starting at the top repeating the process.

Example would be a schedule of events that contained scores and users are viewing them at the venue.

Comment: I would do something along the lines of: have `.wrapper` x 5 that is 100VH/100VW or set via jQuery, use jQuery to translate3d to the next `.wrapper` within a setInterval function, if there is no `.wrapper` found, refresh the page.

Do you have any code to share with your attempts?

Comment: I havent started yet, gathering my ideas, hence why I posted this question.

Comment: Do you still need assistance? I recently implemented a replica of http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-5s/ if that's the style you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) to set up an animation loop, then scroll the page with javascript, until the end of the page is reached, and restart.

```
!function scroll() {
    var current = document.body.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight
    if (current == document.body.scrollTop)
        document.body.scrollTop = -1
    document.body.scrollTop += 1
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll)
}()
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VCSgQ/3/)

Comment: That is actually pretty nice.  No way to stop it though at non cut offs of data within the viewport, then scroll?  Not sure a rotating vertical schedule would be easy to read for folks viewing a monitor.

Comment: Not sure I follow you, but you could, under certain conditions, wrap the `raf` in a `setTimeout`, like "have we arrived to a new header? [check `scrollTop` of the next item] if yes, then we chill for a bit and schedule the next animation frame to run/continue in 5 seconds".